# Paginação com GSON (ANDROID)

Tags: android, json, gson, load

Pessoal preciso fazer um load ao chegar no final da list, exemplo tenho 20 items, ao chegar no final da mesma, preciso que seja carregado mais 20.

Atualmente meu Fragment que carrega os anúncios está da seguinte forma abaixo.

```
        new AsyncHttpClient().get(Constantes.URL_WS_BASE + "anuncio/list", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            if(response != null) {
                Type type = new TypeToken<List<Anuncio>>() {}.getType ();
                 anuncios = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), type);

                AnuncioRecyclerAdapter adapter = new AnuncioRecyclerAdapter(anuncios);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Houve um erro ao carregar a lista de anúncios.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            lytLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Falha: " + responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Não consegui dessa forma, estou com bastante dificuldade em fazer isto.

Comment: Então cara, mas por exemplo "anuncio/list" retorna todos os itens?! Porque se retorna tudo não faz muito sentido ter paginação. Geralmente faço assim "anuncio/list/10,0" retornando 10 itens da pagina 1, no final da lista (na media que usa o scroll), faço uma nova busca "anuncio/list/10,1" retornando mais 10 itens da pagina 2;